# Is the merging of DEPENDENT Bernoulli processes still a Bernoulli process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

This is the question:

> Suppose that the two Bernoulli processes $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are
>   dependent. We still assume, however, that the pairs ($X_n, Y_n$) are
>   independent. E.g., ($X_2, Y_2$) is independent from ($X_1, Y_1$), etc.
>
> Is $Z_n$, the process formed by recording an arrival in a given time
>   slot if and only if both of the original processes record an arrival
>   in that same time slot, guaranteed to be a Bernoulli process?

The text answer is `no`, but I have difficulties to find a case where, given the assumptions, the merged process would not be a Bernoulli one.

For example, I may think that the dependency of $Y$ to $X$ changes with time, but if so $Y_n$ would have a different probability across time slots, and it would not have been a Bernoulli process to start with..

EDIT:

I am still thinking to the merging of two DEPENDENT Bernoulli processes.
For example $p_{X}(x=1) = 0.7$ and $p_{Y|X}(y=1|x= 0) = 0.2, p_{Y|X}(y=1|x= 1) = 0.8$.

The second stream and the merged one are, on my thought, Bernoulli processes *a priori* (with $p_Z(z=1) = 0.7*0.8$), but not *a posteriori* conditional to the realisation of the X stream, as the time homogeneity property would then be lost.

Am I right ?

Everywhere* you read about Bernoulli processes merging, it is referred to independent ones (with the independent word often highlighted), while for me this is irrelevant (obviously $p_Z$ would be different in the two cases).

*for example:

- https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF08_lec20.pdf
- http://ocw.metu.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/8197/mod_resource/content/1/EE230_lecture27-print.pdf
- http://slpl.cse.nsysu.edu.tw/cpchen/courses/probability/arrivalProcess.pdf
- http://web.it.nctu.edu.tw/~chungliu/courses/StochasticProcesses/slides/Chapter5.pdf
- http://www.telecom.otago.ac.nz/tele302/ref/Bertsekas_ch5.pdf
- https://www.scribd.com/document/324508062/Bernoulli-Process-pdf

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but if you have a sequence of mutually independent vectors $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and you define $Z_i = f(X_i,Y_i)$ for some deterministic and measurable function $f$, then $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of mutually independent random variables.  In your case I think $X_i , Y_i$ are binary-valued and $f(X_i,Y_i) = \min[X_i,Y_i]$, so $Z_i$ is also binary-valued.

Comment: You could of course have $\{X_i\}$ iid, $\{Y_i\}$ iid, and the vectors $\{(X_i,Y_i)\}$ iid, but play around with dependencies between $X_i$ and $Y_i$ (such as alternating $X_i=Y_i$ for odd $i$ and $X_i$ indep of  $Y_i$ on even $i$) to make the $Z_i$ variables have distribution that depends on $i$.

Comment: To provide a concrete example of @Michael's comment: flip two numbered coins. $X_i$ records "Heads on coin 1"; $Y_i$ records "Heads on coin 1 if $i$ is odd, or on coin 2 if $i$ is even." Then $Z_i$ alternates probabilities $1/2$ and $1/4$.

Comment: @Michael , ConnorHarris:  Yes, but in your examples the dependent process would not be a Bernoulli process to start with, because of time variability. What the text claims (and that I suspect to be wrong) is that the merging with rule AND of two dependent *Bernoulli processes* may not be a Bernoulli process.

Comment: Antonello : Why do you say that "the dependent process would not be a Bernoulli process to start with"?  I give my example again in more detail below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example again, in a bit more detail, is this. I will use $X_i$ and $W_i$ for the 0/1 outcome for Connor's two coins on flip $i$.  Define:

- Coin 1: $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ i.i.d. Bernoulli, $P[X_i=1]=P[X_i=0]=1/2$.
- Coin 2: $\{W_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ i.i.d. Bernoulli,  $P[W_i=1]=P[W_i=0]=1/2$.
- Assume $\{X_i\}$ and $\{W_i\}$ are independent.
- For $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ define $Y_i = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
  X_i &\mbox{ if $i$ is odd} \\
  W_i  & \mbox{ if $i$ is even} 
  \end{array}
  \right.$
- For $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ define  $Z_i = \min[X_i, Y_i]$.

Thus, $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is an i.i.d. Bernoulli process with $P[X_i=1]=1/2$ for all $i$.   Likewise, $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is an i.i.d. Bernoulli process with $P[Y_i=1]=1/2$ for all $i$. Also, $\{Z_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of mutually independent random variables, but is not i.i.d. since $P[Z_i=1]$ depends on $i$.